# Displaying Custom message in Linux when an user logs in

Tags: linux, ssh, server-administration

I have a Linux server running SSH service. I have a custom message which needs to be displayed when an user logs in using putty.
The required screenshot is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIvVv.jpg)
Can any one tell me how to achieve the same ?

Comment: screen shot seems to be missing, I think you need something like `motd`

Comment: Depends on whether this is specific to a user or not. If it is user specific, then your would need to amend /home/username/.profile or /home/username/.bashrc.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [sf].

Answer (score 4):

To display Welcome or Warning message for SSH users **before** login. Use issue.net file

```
vi /etc/issue.net
```

Add the banner message of your choice, and save the file

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Search for the word 'Banner'

Change `#Banner /some/path` To `Banner /etc/issue.net`

```
service sshd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorials explaining how to do this in detail, but the tl;dr version is this:

> You need to edit two files:
>
> - `/etc/motd` (Message of the Day)
> - `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` : Change the setting PrintLastLog to "no",    this will disable the "Last login" message.
>
> And then restart your sshd. [SOURCE](https://serverfault.com/questions/407033/how-can-i-edit-the-welcome-message-when-ssh-start)

Hope it helps